# Making an element 100% the width of its grandparent

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm trying to make an element dynamically match the width of its grandparent (using "width: 100%"). I can't modify the grandparent, because the element in question could be inserted into a bunch of different places all with different grandparent elements. Is there a way using CSS or SCSS to make an element match the width of its grandparent?

I also can't just make the parent width: 100% and the element width: 100%, because that breaks other things.

The other solutions already posted rely on being able to modify the grandparent, and don't work in this case.

```
<Grandparent>     //Can't modify grandparent
   <Parent>       //Width is different to that of the grandparent
      <Element/>  
   <Parent/>
<Grandparent/>
```

```
Parent {
   width:auto;
}
Element {
   width:100%; //This makes the element the same width as the Parent instead of the Grandparent
}
```

Comment: Please show an example of your HTML and explain clearly which elements should behave as you describe. We can't help with such a vague question.

Comment: So if the parent woder than the grandparent what do you want to to? Horizontal scrollbar? Maybe real example will make more sense.

Comment: Maybe real code would help here....

Comment: Here I wrote two possible solutions. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: add position absolute and width 100% to the child, no position to parent and position relative to grandparent:

```
<div class="grandparent"> GrandParent
    <div class="parent"> Parent
        <div class="child"> Child</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .grandparent {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        background: orange;
    }

    .parent {
        width: 150px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .child {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        background: lightgrey;
    }
</style>
```

**Solution 2**: create a class and add it to the grandparent and the child:

```
<div class="grandparent common-width"> GrandParent
    <div class="parent"> Parent
        <div class="child common-width"> Child</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .grandparent {
        width: 300px;
        background: orange;
    }

    .parent {
        width: 150px;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .child {
        background: lightgrey;
    }

    .common-width {
        width: 240px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these solutions only work if you can modify the grandparent. In my case, there's no guarantee that the grandparent has position:relative or a common class. But thanks for your interest!